# krusader permission (root and non-root)

Tags: 20.04, permissions, krusader

I just switched from win10 to ubuntu 22.04. krusader is very similar to total commander on win. After apt-get krusader, I find clicking the icon doesn't start the app. After one night googling, I realize it needs sudo to start. (I vaguely remember I just clicked its icon to start it last time).

Is it true krusader can't start in regular non-root mode after it's installed with sudo? If it can, how can I make it happen?

is there a way to make launcher with sudo so that I don't need to type sudo krusader every time in the terminal? Any tool or sw package to make that easier?

Thanks.

update1: Without root, krusader just hang there

```
$ krusader
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
20:59:12.865-debug default unknown@0 # System icon theme: "Yaru"
20:59:12.902-warning default unknown@0 # QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
20:59:12.903-warning default unknown@0 # QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
20:59:12.909-warning kf.i18n unknown@0 # Trying to convert empty KLocalizedString to QString.
```

Comment: Krusader can run perfectly fine as non-root, and you should not use it with sudo permissions for security reasons. Can you start it from the terminal using `krusader` and what does it tell you when you do that?

Comment: @Sebastian updated in the description

Comment: That's the exact same lines I get as well, except for the last one, and I cannot imagine that is the problem. Are you sure you don't have two displays active and it somehow launches on the second one? You may try to remove `~/.config/krusaderrc` to start with a fresh configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sebastian, reconfigure after removing ~/.config/krusaderrc worked.
I have 2 machines for the exactly the same behavior. Not on the 2nd screen as there is no red dot to indicate app is running.

Here is the diff and there are a lot of saved states from old config.

```
$ diff krusaderrc krusaderrc.old
7a8,14
> [Custom Selection Mode]
> Immediate Context Menu=true
> Left Selects=true
> Right Preserves=false
> ShiftCtrl Left Selects=false
> Space Moves Down=true
> 
30a38,40
> [General]
> Editor=sublime
> 
35a46,54
> [KrInterDetailedView]
> AutoResizeColumns=false
> Saved State=\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\xa8\x07\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x02$\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\xda\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00d
> 
> [Look&Feel]
> Mouse Selection=0
> Show Tab Bar On Single Tab=false
> Tab Bar Position=top
> 
37,40c56,59
 PopularUrls=file:///home/ying/,file:///home/ying/Downloads/,file:///opt/ttf/,file:///opt/,file:///
> PopularUrlsRank=24,20,16,15,14
> Start Position=143,414
> Start Size=999,618
49,50c68,70
 Splitter Sizes=498,497
> Start To Tray=true
> State=\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfd\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe7\x00\x00\x02\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00n\x00T\x00o\x00o\x00l\x00B\x00a\x00r\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00j\x00o\x00b\x00T\x00o\x00o\x00l\x00B\x00a\x00r\x01\x00\x00\x02|\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00a\x00c\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00T\x00o\x00o\x00l\x00B\x00a\x00r\x01\x00\x00\x03-\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
65c85
 CurrentItems=Templates
74c94
 Saved State=\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\xa8\x07\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x01\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x98\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00d
85c105
 Url=file:///home/ying/Downloads
89,90c109,110
 CurrentItems=amdgpu-install_5.5.50500-1_all.deb,Downloads,Hack-Italic.ttf,ttf,opt,..
> Entrys=file:///home/ying/Downloads,file:///home/ying,file:///opt/ttf,file:///opt,file:///,file:///home/ying
93c113
 AutoResizeColumns=false
```